# Why does nginx use underscores_in_headers?

Tags: nginx

http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES-0.7

Why does nginx filter client request headers that include underscores? Is there an obvious explanation for this?

Comment: For me it seems like a valid question. The only [explanation](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Missing_.28disappearing.29_HTTP_headers) I could find is following:

**This is done in order to prevent ambiguities when mapping headers to CGI variables, as both dashes and underscores are mapped to underscores during that process.**